# Hadoop: Is it possible to chain several Map-Side join together, seems not?

Tags: join, hadoop, mapreduce, chain

Is it possible to chain several Map-side join together? To me it's impossible because we can't sort values using only map (while in reduce we can use secondary sort). So it's impossible to provided sorted value result for next join. Is there any solution to sort the map-side joins result value? Or any solution to chain several map-side joins? Now I can just think of using map-reduce job to sort the values.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the old api (mapred package), then look into the CompositeInputFormat. There's even a blog article from Roberto Congiu that explains in more detail how to use it:

- http://www.congiu.com/node/5

This does require that your data sets are pre-sorted and likely-partitioned

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at Oozie framework from Yahoo:

1. http://incubator.apache.org/oozie/
2. https://github.com/yahoo/oozie